# Unable to connect to Mongo from spring boot

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I have defined the following properties in application.properties

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=192.x.x.x
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
```

In the mongo db i have configured for remote access specifying bind_ip in mogodb.conf

When i run `sudo netstat -ntlp | grep Listen`

I can see the below 
[image]

But when I try connecting from spring boot application connection fails with below exception

```
org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server 192.x.x.x:27017

com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:67) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.8.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:126) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.8.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:117) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.8.2.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_212]
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:64) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.8.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:62) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.8.2.jar:na]
    ... 3 common frames omitted
```

Not sure if Im missing something kindly help as I am new to mongo db. 
Note: My mongo is running on a virtual ubuntu machine.

Comment: could you   connect  to the  server  from your  local (app  client)  with mongo shell  .  or try  telnet  the   ip +port .  may caused  by the firewall

Answer (score 0):

I had configured my Ubuntu over a virtual box so had to enable portforwarding for the VM machine.

Settings->Network->Advanced->Port forwarding ->add the mongo port as an new entry.